# Making a UI change to ABPeoplePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am presenting an ABPeoplePicker instance modally to allow my users to select people from their contact list. I want to allow them to select multiple contacts at once, so I `return NO;` to this method: `- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{`

When the user selects a contact, in addition to my logic I'm doing to "save" the contact for use later, I want to put a check mark of sorts next to the contact to show it has been selected. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, you shouldn’t try to modify the UI of any view controllers provided by Apple. Sure, you might be able to hack something together, get it working, and achieve your goal, but what happens when iOS 6 or 7 stomps all over this UI and breaks your app? For this reason, doing so will *probably* get you rejected by Apple in the first plce before you’re even in the App Store.

So, let’s look at this from the opposite perspective. You want a UI that allows multiple selection of Address Book contacts with a checkmark in the table view. Why not create that table view? You can use the Address Book framework to populate the table view with the user’s address book data, recreating what you need from the built-in UI, but with your modifications. Check out the [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html) for a starting point.

Comment: That makes sense. And it is the approach I took. Someone posted a sample of how to do this to a different question and I got it working based off that. Thanks for the feedback.